# Faster/better: Fetch a few JSON-objects with PHP or JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Personally I would do this with PHP but maybe someone has an pro/contra for doing this with JavaScript:

- I (will) fetch a few song details (about ten per page load) from Soundcloud
- afterwards the statistic (played this week/total, liked this week/total etc.) will be displayed in a table

That's it - nothing special.

---

I can solve it like this:

- let PHP do the stuff and render the whole page at once

This will of course take some time before the page is rendered.

Is there any advantage of doing this with JavaScript? I can only think of:

- the page renders faster (with the disadvantage that the results may not be displayed instantly)

Comment: Just do it. The bigger issues are: Is there an API token/secret that must be sent? Does it support JSONP or how does the cross-site XHR work? Is the Soundcloud API flexible enough for the task? What is Soundcloud's access policy? Etc.

Comment: @pst My thoughts exactly. You wouldn't want to expose any authentication params within the view. insertusernamehere: Security aside, JS = fast initial page load with the opportunity for a loading screen ( better? ). PHP = Initial page load waits for response on curl or whatever you're doing to create a session. Perhaps build both and make your choice after you see how they perform.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @pst: Yes, it supports JSONP. And you both are saying some good points. I will go with PHP in this case, as everything will be there right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that doing it via JavaScript will actually take longer, as you'll have to connect again.  Although, it may give an illusion of "being faster" (though I doubt it'll be noticeable).

I suppose it might depend on your usage cases too.

How are you handling authentication with SoundCloud?

Comment: That's what I thought. So I will use PHP this time, as it's only for a few tracks and I can store the results in a session and don't have to reconnect all the time. Oh, and to answer your question: They use  OAuth 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly go the jQuery route.

Use a `$.post()` call, and within your `success` statement, loop through the json and append it to a table. This way, you can do something like pagination, which can update your table without needing to refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Those are good arguments for a page with a lot of sounds, with pagination and many requests. For a bigger project than the current one this is a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do it serverside and pre-load the page. The soundcloud API should not be the bottleneck here so reducing a request or two is worth it.

Comment: That's what I thought and in this case it really won't be more than a few tracks on a page without any pagination etc.